# Using Eclipse with multiple branches

Tags: eclipse, git, branch

I am new to serious programming and just decided to start using Git and GitHub to manage my projects more effectively. I created a local repo, synchronised it with a remote on GitHub, and created new branch for testing new concept. All works fine, but when I click on this new branch in Eclipse the changes affect only this branch. This is fine too, but I do not understand how it works.

I have single folder on my computer, which I can preview with right-click on a project -> Properties.  This shows

> C:\Users\UserName\git\VocabularyLearningRepo\VocabularyLearning

and there are only single files - I supposed it will create two sets of files for every branch and I will just switch between it.

Where are my two different projects (from two branches) stored? Or is there only one file and all changes in different branches are displayed by stuff from 'git' folder?

Which branch is physically in the one file I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At any given time you will only have one set of files in your project directory, which in git terminology is the working tree.  When you checkout a revision, even when switching branches, your working directory is updated to reflect that revision.

The revisions in your repo are stored under the *.git* directory, just not in a format that makes much sense outside if you go looking by hand.